map<MyData*> without a second item?
My legacy code uses a red-black tree to store pointers to homogeneous (typically POD) objects.  Let's call one MyPod.  My compare function compares pointers to two such objects based on whatever criteria is required.  What I'm trying to find isn't a SECOND thing, but just the pointer already in the red-black tree.
To use std::map<> I think I'd have to map std::Map<MyPod*, MyPod*>?  Seems wasteful to have the same pointer twice.  Is there another collection I should consider?  Can I make the second item void, or replace the pair<> with a single pointer, or make the pair a union, or something?

Are you aware about std::set?

Important note: If you use a pointer as the key (in a map or in a set) it's the pointer that is the key, not the object it points to. If you have two distinct objects that are supposed to be "equal", the pointers to them will be different therefore they will each have a different entry in the map or set.

it's the pointer that is the key--doesn't my compare function determine equality and sorting order?  If I choose to dereference the pointers and look at (say) their name field, the STL will trust me, no?

Only if you have a suitable ordering function for the map or set. If you don't the default are the pointers themselves that are used.

If the MyPod compare function that determines equality and sorting order depends on the state of the object pointed to, and the object pointed to is mutable, and the mutable parts of the object affect the compare function that determines equality and sorting order, then there will be coherence problems if the object changes state.  The workaround is to remove the object from the std::set, modify it, then add it back into the std::set.

As others noted, study the existing containers. See for example cppreference.com. Apart from that, you have requirements that brought you to believe that std::map is almost the right type. However, it would be much better if you provided the requirements, not just your (possibly flawed!) conclusion that std::map fits.

Only if you have a suitable ordering function for the map or set--@Someprogrammerdude As I said: "My compare function..."

there will be coherence problems if the object changes state--@Eljay   Sure.  The same is true of any other use of map.  Use phone number, say, as the key, then if the phone number changes you have to remove the old and add the new.  It's a critical thing for people to remember so thank you for the caution.

that would not match what your question states @JaMiT -- If you're not a native English speaker, then note the part of the question you didn't quote clarifies my intent.  If you are a native English speaker, please don't pick fights by selectively quoting.  I'm not going to fight you.

You can just use std::set<MyPod*> instead of a std::Map<MyPod*, MyPod*>.

Also worth asking: std::set<MyPod*> or std::set<std::shared_ptr<MyPod>>?
